# android ngn stack and motorola XT912 android chashes

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to use IMSDROID (android ngn stack) SIP stack on an android Motorola XT912.

I've tested the android ngn stack on other android phones but there were no problems. Need some help.

Thx!